# how can I pass multiple parameters in javascript function

Tags: javascript

```
function ceshi(test,lyj,param1,parm2){
    console.log(arguments)
}
var params = [2,3];
ceshi(eval('2,3'));
```

if params is not uncertain, how can I pass params through a method.I want to realize below result.

the function has fixed params,but I have more than one function like

```
ceshi(1,2,123)
ceshi(1,3123)
ceshi('xxx','ssssss','12313',12)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override Javascript Function Based on Passed Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738508/override-javascript-function-based-on-passed-parameters)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass unknown number of arguments into javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116608/pass-unknown-number-of-arguments-into-javascript-function)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To call a function, by passing arguments from an array

1. Either use spread operator `ceshi(...params)`
2. Use `apply` function to invoke it `ceshi.apply(<Context>, params)`

Comment: yeah ,maybe I don`t express my meaning about this question,but you know my meaning,thank you, ceshi.apply(this,params),can work,it can provide our a dynamic method to defined a array to pass it to function, thanx u.But your first suggestion i can`t get the point how can i use it

Comment: [see this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for know about `spread operator` in javascript

Answer (score 16):

You can use spread operator in ECMAScript 6 like this:

```
function ceshi(...params) {
  console.log(params[0]);
  console.log(params[1]);
  console.log(params[2]);
}
```

Or use the "arguments" variable within a function like this:

```
function ceshi() {
  console.log(arguments[0]);
  console.log(arguments[1]);
  console.log(arguments[2]);
}
```

To understand further deeper, I will highly recommend you to read [this material](http://javascript.info/rest-parameters-spread-operator).

Comment: thanx bro, maybe i confused you, i choose the best answer

Comment: This is a best answer

Answer (score 2):

You can set params with object, for example:

```
        function ceshi(options)
        { 
            var param1= options.param1 || "dafaultValue1";
            var param2= options.param2 || "defaultValue2";
            console.log(param1);
            console.log(param2);
        }

        ceshi({param1: "value1", param2:"value2"});
        ceshi({param2:"value2"});
        ceshi({param1: "value1"});
```

Comment: thanx bro, maybe i confused you, i choose the best answer